# Calling java method from Android WebView

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-webview

I want to show a html image map in my android app. For this I use WebView, and I want when a `<area>` is clicked, the clicked area to do something.
For example if I use kicked or touched 'North Carolina', I show name of it in a toast.

My code is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>map_usa_856</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="usamap.png" width="320" height="266" style="margin:0 auto; display:block;" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="poly" href="North Carolina" alt="North Carolina" title="North Carolina" coords="266,109,267,107,270,107,270,105,273,102,278,100,277,98,275,98,276,96,278,96,280,93,278,91,277,91,278,90,277,88,245,93,244,97,242,97,239,100,236,102,233,102,232,104,231,104,231,105,237,104,240,102,250,102,250,102,252,104,258,102">
      <area shape="poly" href="North Dakota" alt="North Dakota" title="North Dakota" coords="119,17,152,17,155,38,118,36">
      <area shape="poly" href="Rhode Island" alt="Rhode Island" title="Rhode Island" coords="289,48,291,53,292,52,302,54,302,57,311,57,311,51,302,51,302,53,292,51,291,48">
      <area shape="poly" href="Illinois" alt="Illinois" title="Illinois" coords="208,79,207,80,208,82,207,85,205,87,205,91,203,93,203,93,202,93,200,93,200,95,198,93,199,90,192,87,194,82,191,82,190,82,190,80,185,77,185,75,187,69,187,67,190,67,192,62,189,60,204,59,204,60,206,62">
      <area shape="poly" href="New Mexico" alt="New Mexico" title="New Mexico" coords="117,96,83,93,78,130,83,131,84,127,92,129,92,127,115,129">     <area shape="poly"  alt="Georgia" title="Georgia" coords="255,123,252,123,252,120,250,119,249,117,247,117,246,114,242,114,241,111,240,109,237,107,236,107,236,105,222,107,227,121,231,125,229,127,229,130,229,132,231,134,247,133,247,134,249,131,252,131,252,128,252,125,254,124">
    </map>
  </body>
</html>
```

I found this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        Log.e("String HrefValue :-",url);
    }
});
```

But it doesn't give me the answer I want. Can you give a hand for this?

Answer (score 5):

According [w3c specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area#attr-href) the href attribute for `<area>` must be a valid URL. Obviously "North Carolina" is not a [valid URL](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt). That's is your primary issue.

Now, you need to display a Toast message when user click on an `<area>`. Displaying a Toast message must be done in java code and Android provide you a very easy way to [call some java method from javascript](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript).

In your Activity code: write a method to display a Toast and annotate it with `@JavascriptInterface` :

```
/** Show a toast from the web page. (this method will be called by javascript) */
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String areaName) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked on "+areaName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You must also:

- enable javascript in your webview
- *inject* your *javascript interface* in the webview

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
//enable javascript
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//all methods annotated with @JavascriptInterface are callable 
//from javascript by using the "Android" object.
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
```

Finally in your html code : use a correct url calling javascript `Android.showToast(...)` for `<area href=...>` :

```
  <area shape="poly" href="javascript:Android.showToast('North Carolina');return false;" alt="North Carolina" title="North Carolina" coords="266,109,267,107,270,107,270,105,273,102,278,100,277,98,275,98,276,96,278,96,280,93,278,91,277,91,278,90,277,88,245,93,244,97,242,97,239,100,236,102,233,102,232,104,231,104,231,105,237,104,240,102,250,102,250,102,252,104,258,102">
```

Comment: tnx tnx tnx for this.

Comment: but one thing, when i write this and run it, i see error : `Error:(25, 30) java: ';' expected` infact 2 of this error show.

Comment: It is a simple syntax error, look at red lines in your ide and fix them (the code to setup the webview must be in the `onCreate(Bundle)` method.

Comment: my code is  `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("somthing");
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String areaName) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked on "+areaName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`
    } and Error tell me I am missing some semicolen from  `public void showToast(String areaName)`